# 2 inline divs in one row, when the left one gets too large, the right one goes under the other

Tags: html, css

I have this situation:
I got a wrapper div with set width 790px.
I got two inline divs (left and right) with width 390px. 
This is because of legacy issues, otherwise I wouldn't set them with fixed pixels.
So the problem is when the left one expands and gets more than 390px, the right one gets under the left one. I want if the left one expands and gets bigger, the left one to shrink. The left one would never take more than 70% of the space in the wrapper. But I can't set the right one's width to 30%, because I want when they both aren't full, to have equal sizes. Any ideas? The 390px rull can be removed for those divs, but how should I adjust it?

Comment: Do you try to use max-width?

Comment: Yes I did. When I set the max-width to 55%, if the right is also full, it goes under the left one.

Comment: Could you possibly post the code / jsfiddle?

Comment: And another problem is that even if I have max-width 55%, the left column expands much more than 55%.

Answer (score 3):

Float the first div and set the desired min and max width. Add overflow hidden to the other div:

```css
body {
  font: medium sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 790px;
  background: #CCC;
}
.wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.wrapper > div:first-child {
  float: left;
  min-width: 50%;
  max-width: 70%;
  background: #FC0;
}
.wrapper > div:last-child {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #0CF;
}
```

```html
<p>Case 1</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
<p>Case 2</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed turpis libero, luctus at tincidunt eget, mollis eget augue. Praesent eu.</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
<p>Case 3</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed turpis libero, luctus at tincidunt eget, mollis eget augue. Praesent eu.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class='wrap'>
<div class='span'>*tree view for a folder system*</div>
<div class='span'>file names in the folder</div>
</div>
```

css:
    span {
        display: inline-table;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .span {
        width: 390px;
    }

```
.wrap {
    border: 0 none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    width: 790px
}
```